# Telerik RadAsyncUpload issue with FireFox 6

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

RadAsyncUpload (latest) is not working with Mozilla 5 browsers.  I have tested it with FireFox 6, and it hangs halfway through progress.  When refreshing, forms authentication fails and it returns you to the login page.  I have tested with the same browser using the Telerik demos site, and it fails there.  It appears that jQuery Upload has the same problem.

In my case, I get a generic error when tracing the error - "/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" with no details on the error. I have been at this for a few days and have a ticket into Telerik.

The control works fine with all the latest browsers, but people still use AOL, old FireFox browsers, and old versions of Safari.

Has anyone else had this issue, or can anyone shed some light on what's going on?  Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: What did they say? I think such old browsers are not supported by them: http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tech-sheets/browser-support and I doubt there would be a resolution. Considering that other solutions don't work either, there is probably something wrong with the browser (it is 4 years old). You can try the regular <input type='file'> or the <asp:FileUpload> control.

Comment: That was pretty much the response I got.  I implemented browser-update.org on my site for the browsers I knew were failing.